# when $y-\sin(x) \ge 0 $? feasible set

Tags: inequality, optimization, nonlinear-optimization

Well that's the question, I have the graph of the function in the interval  $0 \lt x \lt \frac{3 \pi}{2 }$and I need to know (in order to get a feasible set) when this inequality stands:$ y- \sin(x) \ge 0$, I tried cutting the function in $\pi$, and then I gave two values in both sides of areas, $\gt \pi$ and $\lt \pi$, but the function is negative when $x \lt \pi $ even when the graph shows the area over the $x$ axis... so I don't understand... I also don't understand where should the feasible region be... I mean, should I paint all the area until reach $\pi$ assuming that only one side of the total area is feasible?

Sorry for this silly question, it's just that recently I had to take a lot of this again soIi can get the basics for non linear optimization.

I would really appreciate your help. Thanks

Comment: The question doesn't make sense, and the explanation is (at least) not helpful: $0=0$ is not an interval, it is not clear what cutting a function in pi is, and whatever follows these two things is incomprehensible.

Comment: yeah i realize i didn't write the question well because of my keyboard, so sorry for the problems... i'm also still practicing my english :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that when written in standard form, this equation is $y \geq \sin{x}$. This means that all values of y in the *entire* coordinate plane that are *greater than* or *equal* to $\sin{x}$ will yield a valid solution.

The thing with the question they gave you is that it does not ask for a particular **set of x such that $\mathbf{\sin{x}\geq0}$**. The answer to the previous question is $[0,\pi]$ because $\sin{x}\geq0$ in this region. This is NOT the question they asked you.

What they asked you was to find all points (x,y) that satisfy the inequality- including points that are not part of the graph $y \mathbf{=}\sin{x}$ (Notice the equals sign). Take a look at the graph
https://www.desmos.com/calculator/fhgwbtbgdu (Notice that the curve $\sin{x}$ of the graph is a solid line instead of a dotted because it is $\geq$ instead of $\gt$.

Your inequality is as simplified as it can get, so technically that **is** your answer or you can represent your answer through the graph. That region is all the points where the solution is valid. For example, take $(2,\pi)$ as a point. A quick check will show you that $$y-\sin{x}\geq0$$$$2-\sin{\pi}\geq0$$$$2-0\geq0$$$$2\geq0$$
which is true.

Comment: Thanks so much Ian :D i'm sorry if the question was silly, i have like 4 years without doing this stuff... but you really helped me. This is what i was looking for!!!

Comment: Your question wasn't silly at all. You should be proud for your interest :)